# What is the best way to trim a string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to trim a this character consist of a chinese character.

```
Select '10樓 10 /F'
Select '7樓 7/F'

Bad Result:

10樓 10 /F
7樓 7/F

I want to this:

10/F
7/F
```

Comment: How do you decide to eliminate first 7 and 10 ?

Comment: So what are the actual rule(s) here? Trying to infer them from two very similar examples may lead to wildly different interpretations. E.g. I could implement the rule "remove everything before the first space and any remaining space characters" - but is that (close to) the actual rule?

Comment: I just want to remove the left from '10樓 10 /F' to '10/F'

Comment: But again, from just two examples, we could hard code it. If there are only two variations, do that. If there are more variations, try to tell us about them. E.g. is `樓` the *only possible character to need elimination*? Will it always occupy the same logical position?

Comment: I want to remove this character 樓 starting with it then remove the rest from the left. The result like this 10/F

Comment: You need to either have a black list or a white list - so you know either all chars to remove or all chars to keep. Without that, you'll be fighting blind-folded with your hands tied behind your back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CHARINDEX to find the position of the chinese character.
Then use SUBSTRING to get the part you need based on that position.
And REPLACE all the spaces to nothing from that result.

For example:

```
select * , replace(substring(value, charindex(N'樓',value)+1, len(value)),' ','') as value2
from (values 
 (N'10樓 10 /F'),
 (N'7樓 7/F')
) v(value);
```

Note that putting the N before the strings marks them as NVARCHAR.
Since the chinese character is a unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
with cte as (
    select '10樓 10 /F' as t
    union all
    select '7樓 7/F'
)
select rtrim(ltrim(substring(t, charindex('樓', t) + 1, len(t)))) as t
from cte
```

Comment: wow, this is good! but how to express the charindex() to a dynamic or regular expression or a pattern? example, like this 3北翼 3/F to 3/F?

Comment: Can you define all ASCII codes of incorrect characters? In this case you can replace them, and after that find a right one position.

Comment: @PatrickPangilinan - suddenly, in a comment, there's another example that's quite different from the first two. That's the sort of thing I've been *asking* you to add to your question. Otherwise, we can just expect than any given answer is going to have you adding another comment with another example for which the answer does not work.